# What are the units of UDP buffers, and where are docs for sysctl params?

Tags: linux, sockets, udp, buffer, sysctl

I'm running x86_64 RedHat 5.3 (kernel 2.6.18) and looking specifically at net.core.rmem_max from sysctl -a in the context of trying to set UDP buffers. The receiver application misses packets sometimes, but I think the buffer is already plenty large, depending upon what it means:

What are the units of this setting -- bits, bytes, packets, or pages? If bits or bytes, is it from the datagram/ payload (such as 100 bytes) or the network MTU size (~1500 bytes)? If pages, what's the page size in bytes?

And is this the max per system, per physical device (NIC), per virtual device (VLAN), per process, per thread, per socket/ per multicast group?

For example, suppose my data is 100 bytes per message, and each network packet holds 2 messages, and I want to be able to buffer 50,000 messages per socket, and I open 3 sockets per thread on each of 4 threads. How big should net.core.rmem_max be? Likewise, when I set socket options inside the application, are the units payload bytes, so 5000000 on each socket in this case?

Finally, in general how would I find details of the units for the parameters I see via sysctl -a? I have similar units and per X questions about other parameters such as net.core.netdev_max_backlog and net.ipv4.igmp_max_memberships.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You'd look at [these](http://kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/net.txt) docs. That said, many of these parameters really are quite poorly documented, so do expect do do som googling to dig out the gory details from blogs and mailinglists.

rmem_max is the per socket maximum buffer, in bytes. Digging around, this appears to be the memory where whole packets are received, so the size have to include the sizes of whatever/ip/udp headers as well - though this area is quite fuzzy to me.

Keep in mind though, UDP *is* unreliable. There's a lot of sources for loss, not the least inbetween switches and routers - these have buffers as well.

Answer (score 2):

It is fully documented in the socket(7) man page (it is in bytes).

Moreover, the limit may be set on a per-socket basis with SO_RCVBUF (as documented in the same page).

Read the socket(7), ip(7) and udp(7) man pages for information on how these things actually work. The sysctls are documented there.